# Where did these features go in Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: layout, android-studio-2.2, graphical-layout-editor

Where did these features go in android studio 2.2:

1. In the design layout view, before in v2.1 when you dragged an element (ex button) around a popup showed which property to apply (ex width: match_parent).  In v2.2 i see a line where its being moved to, but no popup telling me what its doing.
2. Also in design layout view, it seems Component Tree is part of Pallet and are linked in same view.  How can i separate them so i can toggle Pallet off but keep Component Tree open.  (I do like the move to separate properties from Component Tree)

It's cool they are adding new things. But its annoying when features i rely on are removed or made difficult to find.  If anyone knows some shortcut or option I'm missing to switch these back to the old way. Please let me know. Thank you.